# How to parse this javascript array?

Tags: javascript, parsing, multidimensional-array, menuitem

I am trying to parse a javascript array with objects, similar to this:

```
function Obj(MenuText, stuff, someStuff) {
    this.text = MenuText;
    this.stuff = stuff;
        this.someStuff = someStuff;
}

myArray[0] = new Array();
myArray[0][1] = new Obj('MenuText', 'A', 'F');
myArray[0][2] = new Obj('MenuText2', 'A', 'F');
myArray[1] = new Array();
myArray[1][1] = new Obj('Submenu Option', 'A', 'F');
myArray[2] = new Array();
myArray[2][1] = new Obj('Submenu Option', 'A', 'F');
```

What I need is to parse the array in a way that I could create a list in this way:

```
<ul>
<li>MenuText
<ul>
<li>Submenu Option</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>MenuText2
<ul><li>Submenu Option2</li></ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

So, the menu option for the menu items, are contained in the next main position, for example, button for menu item 4 will be at myArray[0][3].MenuText, but options that will be displayed are at myArray[3][1...N], it is like if you have to invert indexes.

I hope I have been clear enough, thank you very much guys, any recommendation or idea would be really appreciated, it is an issue that has been giving me few errors and I can not solve.

thanks!

Comment: There is an answer here using jQuery:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833683/jquery-looping-over-arrays

Comment: I am trying to avoid jQuery, cause the structure is allready defined and it can not be changed, I must use pure javascript, it is a big and old proyect, including jQuery will be a disaster because it is using an odd version of prototype...thnaks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery, but your object structure seems odd.

It would make more sense to nest the submenus in the object structure in the same manner that they will be nested in the DOM result.

```
var myArray = [];

function Obj(MenuText, stuff, someStuff) {
    this.text = MenuText;
    this.stuff = stuff;
    this.someStuff = someStuff;
}

myArray[0] = new Obj('MenuText', 'A', 'F');
myArray[0].submenu = new Obj('Submenu Option', 'A', 'F');

myArray[1] = new Obj('MenuText2', 'A', 'F');
myArray[1].submenu = new Obj('Submenu Option', 'A', 'F');
```

Then make a recursive function that iterates the array, and make the recursive call when a submenu is found.

```
function makeMenu(menu, parent) {
    var li = parent.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(menu.text));

    if (menu.submenu)
        makeMenu(menu.submenu, li.appendChild(document.createElement("ul")));
}

var container = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("ul"));

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    makeMenu(myArray[i], container);
```

This assumes that you will not have more than one submenu under a menu. That doesn't seem likely.

---

If there could in fact be several submenus under a menu, you would make an Array of submenus.

```
function Obj(MenuText, stuff, someStuff) {
    this.text = MenuText;
    this.stuff = stuff;
    this.someStuff = someStuff;
    this.submenus = []; // holds the sub menus
}

myArray[0] = new Obj('MenuText', 'A', 'F');
myArray[0].submenus.push(new Obj('Submenu Option', 'A', 'F'));

myArray[1] = new Obj('MenuText2', 'A', 'F');
myArray[1].submenus.push(new Obj('Submenu Option', 'A', 'F'));
```

And change the code a bit.

```
function makeMenus(menus, parent) {
    for (var i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {
        var li = parent.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(menus[i].text));

        makeMenus(menus[i].submenus, li.appendChild(document.createElement("ul")));
    }
}

makeMenus(myArray, document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("ul")));
```

This structure is a much more natural representation than your existing one.